# VsCode not formatting TS/JS files with single quotes

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

After one of the latest updates to VS Code, when pressing Ctrl+Shift+F In windows, it is auto
formattig all of my code with double instead of single quotes despite my setting it to only use single quotes.

Here is my settings file:

```
{
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"atlascode.jira.workingSite": {
    "baseUrlSuffix": "atlassian.net"
},
"yaml.schemas": {
    "file:///c%3A/Users/kevin/.vscode/extensions/atlassian.atlascode-2.1.5/resources/schemas/pipelines-schema.json": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml"
},
"window.zoomLevel": -1,
"[html]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"git.autofetch": true,
"javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "single",
"prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

}

Is anyone else dealing with this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using prettier?

Comment: I am, and as you can see from the snippet, I have checked the settings in prettier to use single quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your settings file, it seems like you are using prettier for code formatting. 
In the latest updation, prettier changed reading configuration from common settings file to a dedicated file for prettier settings. You can configure prettier via many options they've provided.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

**Example (JSON):**

Create `.prettierrc` file, written in JSON or YAML, with optional extensions: .json/.yaml/.yml (without extension takes precedence).

**.prettierrc**

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Then provide absolute path of `.prettierrc` file in `settings.json` (vscode settings file).

**settings.json**

```
...
"prettier.configPath": "./.prettierrc"
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "./.prettierrc" is a relative path.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Jins Thomas Shaji is very helpful. But except what he said, you also need to add a line in .prettierrc

```
"jsxSingleQuote": true
```

So, conclution:

**.prettierrc**

```
{
"singleQuote": true, 
"jsxSingleQuote": true,
}
```

settings.json

```
"prettier.configPath": "./.prettierrc"
```